# need documentation for using worklight android app with IBM mobile database (soliddb) as backend

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-soliddb

I wish to develop a worklight android app with IBM mobile database (soliddb) as backend which is installed and running in same android mobile/tablet, Please help me with some good URLs/ documentations for my reference.

Thanks

Comment: Can you expend on the use case for this?

Comment: This is for sales team of a company where sales personnel who goes to various client locations. Since the they couldn't expect proper  network in some places , but the data wil be readily available in the local mobile database and when they come in network coverage they can replicate data from server to mobile db and vice versa..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of the IBM mobile database that you mention.

That said, from your comment it sounds like you may want to consider using IBM Worklight's JSONStore functionality instead, which provides exactly what you require (storing data, syncing).

> JSONStore is a lightweight, document-oriented storage system included
>   as a feature of IBM Worklight, and enables persistent storage of JSON
>   documents. Documents in an application are available in JSONStore even
>   when the device running the application is offline. This persistent,
>   always-available storage can be useful for customers, employees, or
>   partners, to give them access to documents when for example there is
>   no network connection to the device.

Check out the training modules and sample projects here:

- [Advanced client-side development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development)

Additional documentation:

- [JSONStore overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en)
- [Worklight adapter integration with JSONStore](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_wl_adapter_integration.html?lang=en)

Comment: Below is the IBM developerworks link for IBM Mobile Database. 
[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/the_free_ibm_mobile_database_for_android?lang=en]

But is there any way to make Worklight to access this database. I just learnt Worklight, I just wanna try this one since I am a DBA.

Comment: You should contact the author of the article.